# How to keep my bike safe around campus?

Tags: safety, lock

I am a new student in the US. I noticed that a lot of bikes were left with only a tire locked on a post. Therefore, I usually locked my bike on the water pipe outside my apartment. I put a U-lock between the water pipe and my bike frame. However, after I left my apartment for a week, it was gone!

Now I have got a new bike, which is an impressive red Giant. I was really worried that it will be stolen again. Can anyone help me by telling me what else I can do to keep my bike safe in that terrible area. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This series should prove informative (I have linked the first of three):
[Hal will show you!](http://vimeo.com/12061685)

Comment: Wow this is cool. I need more U-locks, probably?

Comment: I thought of Hal too when I read the question! The definitive guide.

Comment: @Bickeylikey So others may have a differing opinion but here is how I go about it...

Heavy-duty u-lock (NY Fahgettaboudit Mini) and put that through the rear wheel+frame and a thick, immovable post so as to have as little room as possible for someone to put a prying device in there. I then either use a nice thick cable to go up through the front wheel and back into the u-lock or a second u-lock up front wheel+frame. I use the cable during day hours when I have it in a safe place, out in the open. If I have to leave it longer, in the dark, or someplace a little shady, I use the second u-lock.

Comment: That's an interesting vid, I'd ne ver heard of the guy before. For me, the most valid thing he says is "a lock buys you time". And that's all it buys you. Unfortunately there is no silver bullet.

Comment: @PeteH yes, exactly. I think it's all about increasing your odds of staying safe just for as long as needed. Buying some time, making yours less appealing to the thief than the other bikes on the rack, jamming yours in the middle of the rack in a well lit space (maybe near a security spot), and so on. Nothing is given, but you can certainly improve your odds of having your bike to come back to...